# Position div relatively to icon position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass, css-position

[**THE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4jfv0j8b/)

When a user hovers over a chevron icon next to a name on my website a div appears with options.
**The Problem**: The **names can have different lengths** and I would like to display the div below the chevron no matter how long the name is.

[image]

Here is my code:
**HTML**

```
<div class='settings'><i class='icon ion-chevron-down'></i></div>
<div class='settings-wrapper'>
    <ul class='settings-bubble'>
        <li>Bearbeiten</li> 
        <li>Löschen</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
// The chevron icon 
.settings {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    padding: .1em 0 0 .5em;
    opacity: 0; // I display the chevron on hover using jquery
}

// The options bubble
.settings-wrapper { 
    position: relative; 
}

.settings-bubble {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 .6em;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    li {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        a { float: left; }
    }
}
```

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!!

If I change `left: 0` to `right: 0`it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Woops, adding this as an answer.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you can utilize a wrapper (as you have) and use `right: 0;` rather than left. It should align to the right side of your wrapper.

Comment: Thank you for that! But then it is too far right! And I cannot set the width ofthe name to a fixed with because it can be between 2 and 64 characters in length.

Comment: This is because your ENTIRE content isn't wrapped, only your `bubble` is wrapped. If you contain your `settings` div within the wrapper it should operate properly. So <div wrapper><div settings><div bubble></div></div></div> or something of that nature. Might even need another wrap to contain it all.

Comment: Create a problem demo if possible..

Comment: @NichoIas Hazel added a fiddle! Thank you for all your effort so far!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the icon is hovered, there is an event handler that displays the div. In that handler, you can inspect the x and y coordinates of the icon. When you display the div, you can modify its style to be positioned relative to the icon. For example:

```js
var chevron = document.getElementById('chevron');
var popup = document.getElementById('popup');

chevron.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  popup.classList.remove('hidden');
  popup.style.left = e.target.offsetLeft + 'px';
});

chevron.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  popup.classList.add('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;  
}

#popup {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h1 contenteditable="true">Some long title <span id="chevron">></span></h1>

<div id="popup" class="hidden">popup</div>
```

I left the title editable so you can make it longer and see the popup change position.

Comment: That is really nice!! Is there a way to use a class instead of id? Since I am using my code in a foreach loop. Sorry, I am really new to all this. var chevron = document.getElementByClass('chevron');?

Comment: You can target an element by its class using document.querySelector('.chevron') assuming it's the first element in the document with that class name.

Answer (score 1):

In `.settings-bubble` change `left: 0;` into `right: 0;` and it will stick to the inner right side of the parent instead of the inner left.

EDIT: the trick is to add the div containing the bubble into the div containing the string of arbitrary length, and attach that bubble inside that div to the inner right-hand side, as illustrated by [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnf6bhvz/2/).

Comment: I added a fiddle! Thank you for all your effort so far!!